# Creating single EXE file for project using .Net and another external library

Tags: .net, c++, build, poco, exe

I have an email client created for class that we need to run as a single EXE. It is made with C++ .NET, and the external POCO library, which has a ton of DLL files... What would be the best way to make this happen?

I was looking on some similarly asked questions, and some people recommended tools such as [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22914587-B4AD-4EAE-87CF-B14AE6A939B0&displaylang=en) and Ezirez, but the question only asked for making a single EXE file for .NET, but I want it for both .NET and a 3rd party external POCO library.

Comment: In danger of not getting an "gals" to help you out...

Comment: what the heck is "Ezirez"? No web search hits for it other than this post..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try it with a small test app using 1 POCO and 1 or more .NET DLLs? Then you can post your results and effectively answer your own question if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can you statically link the POCO library and then use ILMerge?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot ILMerge a mixed-mode C++ assembly.